# unable to re-load index from filebeat in elasticsearch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I am new at the ELK stack (more ELG stack as I am using Grafana as the front end instead of kibana for personal reasons). I am using filebeat to send the logs file to the logstash which are then stored in elasticsearch and displayed through grafana. I have used the following guide for the setup: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-getting-started.html

Now when I have added another path in `filebeat.yml` configuration file and then deletes the previous indices in ElasticSearch and then load the template again through the following command,

`filebeat setup --template -E output.logstash.enabled=false -E 'output.elasticsearch.hosts=["localhost:9200"]'`

the index is not registered in elasticsearch and

```
curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v

command show no index in the elasticsearch. After checking the filebeat logs i found the following error.

2018-06-05T10:08:32.228+0500 INFO instance/beat.go:468 Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat]
  Config path: [/etc/filebeat] Data path: [/var/lib/filebeat] Logs path: [/var/log/filebeat]
2018-06-05T10:08:32.229+0500 INFO instance/beat.go:475 Beat UUID: edf1a2c9-0d7d-4c8a-9823-30bf64b72a4f
2018-06-05T10:08:32.229+0500 INFO instance/beat.go:213 Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 6.2.4
2018-06-05T10:08:32.229+0500 INFO elasticsearch/client.go:145 Elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2018-06-05T10:08:32.230+0500 INFO pipeline/module.go:76 Beat name: vbras
2018-06-05T10:08:32.231+0500 INFO elasticsearch/client.go:145 Elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2018-06-05T10:08:32.245+0500 INFO elasticsearch/client.go:690 Connected to Elasticsearch version 6.2.4
```

**`2018-06-05T10:08:32.249+0500 INFO template/load.go:73 Template already exists and will not be overwritten.`**

How to resolve this issue. ?

Answer (score 0):

From [latest version documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-template.html), it is possible to replace index template with following configuration keys:

```
setup.template.overwrite: true
setup.template.enabled: true
```